# Using a state variable in Axios put request in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, react-hooks

I am modifying a state variable `(setTokens(tokens - 1))` in React native and then using the modified variable in an axios PUT request     `(library_tokens: tokens)`.
The problem is, the put request is successful, **but it puts the old value of the variable instead of the modified one in the database after the PUT request**.

The following is the code:

```
const [tokens,setTokens] = useState(0)

const lendBook = book => {

// Add book to the IssueReturn collection in the database

issuesApi
  .post('/bookissue', {
    booksIssued: book._id,

    image: book.image,
    user: context.stateUser.user.userId,
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {

      // Decrement user's library token
      setTokens(tokens - 1);
     
      // Modify the user's library tokens
      userProfileApi
        .put(
          `/${context.stateUser.user.userId}`,
          {
            library_tokens: tokens,
          },
          {
            headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`},
          },
        )
        .then(response => {
          console.log('tokens', tokens);
        });

     
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);


  });
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useEffect like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(tokens) // do something after state has updated
}, [tokens])
```

After state updation the useEffect will be called, so you can call userProfileApi inside useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

setTokens it not a synchron function. code executed afterwards will not have the updated state. either use a local variable to store the result of `token - 1` or make use of the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.